# Is there a printf function in Oracle WebForms?

Tags: oracle, webforms

Is there a function to format a text in Oracle WebForms like printf in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

No, you just have to format the text yourself e.g.

```
text := 'Employee ' || to_char(:blk.empno) || ' earns $' 
        || to_char(:blk.sal,'999999.99');
```